# Данные из C++ кода в python

Tags: c++, python

Можно ли из питона выполнить код, написанный в с++, в частности интересует, можно ли открыть в с++ файл, который имеет не типичный формат, и потом использовать этот открытый в с++ файл в питоне

Comment: [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html) или [Python/C API](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/index.html).

Comment: мне кажется тут про struct